Can't qc.reset() be control gate?
Thanks for looking.
I am conducting the experiment on a simulator on a classical computer
when I run
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer, execute,QuantumRegister,ClassicalRegister

num=4
def reset(n):
   a=QuantumRegister(n,'a')
   qc=QuantumCircuit(a)
   qc.reset(0)
   name="reset"
   qc_reset=qc.to_gate()
   reset_qubit=qc.control(1)
   return reset_qubit
a=QuantumRegister(num,'a')
qc.append(reset(num),range(num))`

I get error 'One or more instructions cannot be converted to a gate. "reset" is not a gate instruction'
I want to initialize a bit to 0 in the gate.

Reseting a qubit to the $|0\rangle$ state is a non-unitary operation in general. I suspect this is the cause of the issue. It’s not clear to me that quantum controlled non-unitary operations are well defined. Perhaps there a way to understand them that I don’t know about.

Related -> https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/32659/are-quantum-controlled-non-unitary-circuit-operations-possible

The answer is no. qc.reset() cannot be a control gate, or any kind of gate for that matter.
The reset operation in qiskit is a special instruction, not a gate (which is basically what the error message you received is trying to tell you). Reset is not reversible and all quantum gates are unitary by definition and therefore reversible.
https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/api/qiskit/circuit_library#built-in-special-instructions

Related to measurements, there is a Reset operation, which produces no
classical data but instructs hardware to return the qubit to the ∣0⟩ state. This is assumed to happen incoherently and to collapse
any entanglement.

https://learning.quantum.ibm.com/tutorial/explore-gates-and-circuits-with-the-quantum-composer#section-non-unitary-operators-and-modifiers

The reset operation returns a qubit to state ∣0⟩, irrespective of its
state before the operation was applied. It is not a reversible
operation.

